# How to pass multiple values one by one in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

In Jmeter I need to test a particular scenario with different customer. I am able to do that using CSV data set config and it's working fine but in my maven java project I want to pass the customerId as -DcustomerId=123456,123457.. something like that.
Is there anyway in Jmeter where I can extract the value of customerId and pass that customerId one by one to test my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Thread Group
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   props.get('customerId').trim().split(',').eachWithIndex { customerId, index ->
       vars.put('customerId_' + ++index, customerId.trim())
   }
   ```

   [image]

   where `props` stands for an instance of [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class instance and `vars` is a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html). Check out [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) for more information on above and other JMeter API shortcuts available for the JSR223 Test Elements.
3. Add [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) after the JSR223 Sampler and configure it as follows:

   [image: customerId]
4. That's it, each JMeter thread (virtual user) will iterate all the customer IDs via the ForEach Controller:

   [image]